# Building HTML table from JSON object via php URL

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, html-table

I'm having issues building an html table with a JSON object that I've already got generated by a php page.

I'm building my JSON object from a spreadsheet where it includes: Fname, Lname, Ext, Rm.

My json.php webpage gives me this result:

```
[{"fName":"John","lName":"Doe","Ext":"#666","Rm":"C3","id":0},{"fName":"Abraham","lName":"Lincoln","Ext":"#917","Rm":"C1","id":1}]
```

So now I'm trying to build an html page filling a table with this data using jquery.
Here's what I've got for my index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="stuff"
<table id="userdata" border="1">
    <thead>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Ext</th>
        <th>Room</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#userdata tbody").html("");
    $.getJSON("json.php", function(data){
            $.each(data.members, function(i,user){
                var tblRow =
                    "<tr>"
                    +"<td>"+user.fName+"</td>"
                    +"<td>"+user.lName+"</td>"
                    +"<td>"+user.Ext+"</td>"
                    +"<td>"+user.Rm+"</td>"
                    +"</tr>"
                $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
            });
        }
    );
});
</script>
```

EDIT:
Found my solution with the following code:

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('collab.json.php');
$data = json_decode($json,true);

echo '<table>';
echo '<tr><th>Username</th><th>Period</th><th>Room</th><th>Next?</th></tr>';

$n = 0;

foreach ($data as $key => $jsons) {
    foreach ($jsons as $key => $value) {
        echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$data[$n]['username'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$data[$n]['period'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$data[$n]['Rm'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$data[$n]['next'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';

    $n++;
} 
}
echo '</table>';
?>

</html>
```

Comment: Where does `members` in  `data.members` comes from? I can't see it anywhere in your json.

Comment: Are you using Firebug or some other tool to see if / where a javascript error is occurring?  If not, I strongly recommend that - otherwise you're taking stabs in the dark.  Additionally, it will let you watch the ajax call, including what is being returned, so you can see if there's any issues there as well.

Comment: cale_b, can you give me a quick rundown on using firebug for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the json you provided is the only output from your `json.php` you have to slightly change this line:

```
$.each(data.members, function(i,user){
```

To this:

```
$.each(data, function(i,user){
```

Comment: No dice with that one. The php file does indeed only echo the JSON object I've built

Comment: So well than tell me where the `members` property is coming from?

Comment: Most likely from a tutorial I was following and I shouldn't have been using it!

Answer (score 0):

usually in these situations, I add the items to an array and then join and append the array. so for example, in your each.

```
tblRow = [
  '<tr>',
    '<td>' + user.fName + '</td>',
    '<td>' + user.lName + '</td>',
    '<td>' + user.Ext + '</td>',
    '<td>' + user.Rm + '</td>',
  '</tr>',
].join('\n');

myArray.push(tblRow);
```

myArray being an empty array outside of your loop, and then after the loop append the array content to your table.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've added: var myArray = newArray(); just above my $.each to no avail

Comment: newArray(); is referencing a function. You want var myArray = []; and that will create the empty array for you.

Comment: No luck. I'm going to get firebug going tonight as I haven't used that in a while, as cale_b mentioned above.